# Fetch Put API to upload image using signed url

Tags: amazon-s3, puppeteer, fetch-api

I am using puppeteer and I have a requirement where I have to upload screenshot on S3.
I am using fetch PUT api with signed url and my image is png format.
Everytime I am getting an error 'failed to fetch'. I have tried keeping image inmemory and in local storage but neither of them working.

Comment: Can you share your code for fetch? Are you using cors?

Comment: I was able to upload the file to s3 using normal xhr call. But now I am facing another issue, where my screenshot is downloaded as 'txt' file. When I opened that I could see the byte array of image as text. 
eg:   137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,3,34,0,0,2,88,8,6,0,0,0,158,131,82,77,0,0,32,0,73,68,65,84,120,156,236,221,119,120,20,213,250,192,241,239,236,102,179,233,141,16,72,239,36,212,16,18,122,9,160,20,233,82,236,88,192,138,5,197,222,11,182,171,63,81,212,107,229,94,149,139.. 
How can I make sure that image is uploaded in correct format and downloaded in the same format?

Comment: That's nice that you can upload something, but can you share the code for upload and download?

Answer (score 0):

```
await page.evaluate(async(signedUrl,screenshot) =>{
        (function generateXHRRequest(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true;

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response));
              }
            };
            xhr.open("PUT", signedUrl);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'image/png');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

            xhr.send(screenshot.data);
        })();
        },signedUrl,screenshot);
    })
```

I have captured screenshot and kept it in memory. Now passing that to the above function. 
Here byte array is copied to file as text and from S3 , when i download file manually, '.txt' file is downloaded.